# Is there a single word to describe the loudest point in a musical composition?

Tags: terminology

Coloquially, *crescendo* is often used--inaccurately--to refer to this. *Climax* might be used, but a musical climax is not necessarily about volume, and this term is not included in the Oxford Dictionary of Music. I am looking for a word used by composers and/or musicologists to particularly refer to the loudest point in a musical composition.

Comment: To be specific, I am thinking of the point at which a composer wishes the interpreter to play more loudly than at any other point in the composition. Therefore, it will likely include the notation "fff" or something more--Stravinsky's Firebird includes a "ffff" and Ligeti's Devil's Staircase includes a "ffffffff." So the question is, is there a term to describe the loudest point in any composition--i.e., that could be used to mean both Stravisnsky's "ffff" and Ligeti's "ffffffff"?

Comment: There really isn't any reason or need for such a term, as the loudest point - nor the quietest, or slowest, or fastest.  That's irrelevant to the overall analysis of a piece.   And BTW,  that is **not** a colloquial use of "crescendo."  If you've seen that in a novel or two, it's just been misused.

Comment: 1) Actually, the use of crescendo in this way is rampant--it far exceeds "a novel or two." This is one reason why it would be nice to have a real word to replace it. 2) Dynamics is irrelevant to the overall analysis of a piece? Funny that composers don't consider them irrelevant to the writing of a piece.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft To clarify, I am an editor, and I see "crescendo" routinely misused in this way. This is exactly what set me off on a search for the proper word. I can easily believe the word I'm looking for does not exist--that's probably why "crescendo" is misused--which would confirm that no such word is "needed." Still, it is clear that "the loudest" and "the slowest moments" are topics that are referred to in both analysis and reviews.

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing the term for a marking for loudest possible volume and the highest volume in a specific piece of music.  There is no end to the number of ffff...'s one can place in sheet music thought I've not seen one past 4.  Also, the loudest volume in a piece may NOT always align with the "climax" of the music in the artistic sense of the term (thought they do often correlate).  Which one were you referring to?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately "rise to a crescendo" has now entered the English language.  But I think musicians still know that a crescendo is the climb, not the summit!

If you find "climax" too vague and you specifically want to refer to the LOUDEST point of a piece, I think you'll have to say "loudest point". Or, if you're thinking in terms of compression, normalisation etc. the 'peak level'.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for "dynamic peak".  Interestingly, this commonly describes the *location* of the maximum, whereas the juxtaposition "peak dynamic" only refers to the value (such as ***fff***).

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see that it necessarily has anything to do with volume or intensity, but solely the intention of the composer. The word 'climax' suggests an end, the word 'crescendo' describes the climb - perhaps we start a new thing here and start calling it 'parte migliore' - literally : the best bit!

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of Sonnet meaning 'it Rings', we could use Levat - 'it lifts'.

We could use Magno Animo, for 'High Spirit'.

Someone else suggested 'Parte Migliore'. I quite like it, or berhaps Migliore - literally just the 'Better'. You could take that compositionally, emotionally, or qualitatively to the performance of the 'stars' of those phrases...

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a word used by composers and/or musicologists to particularly refer to the loudest point in a musical composition.

I am composer, and I would just call it a climax. A climax can of course be other things but volume, but if there is a climax in volume I would just say that that is what there is.

Comment: The problem of course is that a piece can have many climaxes.  Fortunately, language gives us adjectives such as "overall" or "biggest" and others.

Answer (score 1):

The point of culmination, or culminating moment... As in the crescendo culminates and now the rhythm/tempo/volume begins its descent (descendo? A new challenger appears. Lol). Apex works, as does peaks, peak & apex have the bonus of not sounding so final like climax & culminate do, but I think culmination is the "proper-composer-speak" word for it. Though, using culmination may unfortunately look more uppity, than calling a crescendo an uppity looks disassociated lol

Answer (score -2):

FFFF = Fortissississimo, loudest possible

Comment: **1.** lots of composers don't write such extreme dynamic markings (until the late romantic, even **_fff_** was rather outrageous, and in earlier music you may not even find more than **_f_**) **2.** even if a work contains exactly one **_ffff_**, that may not actually be the loudest point. For example, if a symphony contains **_ffff_** for the strings somewhere, then this will sound very intense but not as loud as another place where timpani, cymbals and trombones together hit it at “merely” **_ff_** **3.** dynamics are never written with uppercase letters.